# AJAX load a dynamic page into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

A client needs the url to stay the same on a wordpress website.

So after trying several solutions I think the best way will be through AJAX with the `.load` method.

So down the side of a page there are navigation items controlled by the WordPress engine taking you through to another page.

Is it possible to intercept the outgoing link and load it into a div on the page without having to modify the anchor tags?

Answer (score 1):

This plugin should do what you are looking for:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/ajaxify-wordpress-site/

http://www.swook.net/p/jquery-ajaxify-plugin.html